# How to convert a string to array or return empty array using the ? operator

Tags: php, arrays, string, ternary-operator

I have a attribute of a class that needs to be checked. The variable is a string but I want to convert it to an array if it is not empty, or else return an empty array.

```
'myVariable' => $token->getUser()->getRecord()->getLevel() ?: []
```

As of now, if getLevel() returns something, it returns as a string, but I want an array. Is there a way to do this while keeping the ?: operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it for you:

```
'myVariable' => [$token->getUser()->getRecord()->getLevel()]
```

If `getLevel()` returns a string, you'll end up with an array containing that one string. If `getLevel()` returns nothing, you'll end up with an empty array.

Edit: Check that, you'll end up with an array that contains a NULL element. If that won't work for you, you can try this version, which will give you an array with zero elements:

```
'myVariable' => (array) $token->getUser()->getRecord()->getLevel() ?: []
```

Comment: Intriguing language nuance, that :) Interesting!

Comment: Heh yeah, very subtle but important difference between `(array) null` and `array(null)`.

Comment: Indeed! Actually - could you exclude the shortcut ternary entirely? `(array) null` returns an empty array.

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
'myVariable' => ($token->getUser()->getRecord()->getLevel()!="") ?explode(",",$token->getUser()->getRecord()->getLevel()):array()
```